# Java code for getting data of any type and its subtypes following XSD and JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

```
 <xsd:element name="Address">
     <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
```

i have above xsd. How to define it in java class as any can be like it can be permanent address or it can be correspondence address and they can have subtypes as well. I have tried it with list and Iterator but didn't get all the sub- sub elements

Comment: See the [substitution groups](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_14-Substitution-Groups.html).

Comment: Hi in the above link no where i found "any"

Comment: It's just a hint, I don't have time for the full answer at the moment.

Comment: Why don't you compile this using xjc and see what you get? The XML schema is very likely not the best way of expressing "any element from a subtype hierarchy". Are you stuck with this XML schema or can you change it?

Comment: i got stuck in <xsd:any as there are three elements and all three are having different sub-sub elements and i am using iterator and all these to list but i am not getting complete tags in XML generated after marshalling. How to do this java i tried making @XmlAnyElement in POJO can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it worked by adding tag @XmlSeeAlso

Answer (score 0):

There is the [**xjc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html) tool, that is the part of JDK.
Using *xjc* you can generate java classes from *xsd*
E.g.

```
xjc -p my.java.package MyXsdType.xsd
```

Your `element` is generated to

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected Object any;

public Object getAny() {
    return any;
}

public void setAny(Object value) {
    this.any = value;
}
```

by *xjc*